# have two different validation on a rule if a field exist

Tags: python, validation, conditional-statements, cerberus

I need to parse a lot of yml files.
I have something like the example where in some cases a value exists and because of that I need to change the regex of another rule.
I can't find a way to validate it correctly

yaml1:

```
email: someone@company.com
```

yaml2:

```
email: otherguy@home.com
contract_type: external
```

schema:

```
schema = {
  'email': {
    'required': True,
    'type': 'string',
    'regex': '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@company\.com$'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- The "composite validation" approach allows for conditional (context-aware) validation rules.
- The python `cerberus` package supports composite validation "out of the box".

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- python 2.7
- cerberus validation package
- jmespath query langage (to make validation rules more compact and readable)

#### Problem

- Developer NamenMalkavCreator wishes to apply conditional validation rules.
- The conditional validation rules become activated based on the presence or value other fields in the dataset.
- The conditional validation rules need to be sufficiently flexible to change "on-the-fly" based on any arbitrary states or relationships in the source data.

#### Solution

- This approach can be accomplished with composite data validation.
- Under this use-case, composite validation simply means creating a sequential list of validation rules, such that:

  - Each individual rule operates on a composite data variable
  - Each individual rule specifies a "triggering condition" for when the rule applies
  - Each individual rule produces one of three mutually-exclusive validation outcomes: `validation-success`, `validation-fail`, or `validation-skipped`

#### Example

- The following example assumes multiple YAML documents
- Some sample documents are shown here

Sample documents

```
aadocuments = []
aadocuments.append(yaml.safe_load('''
    person_fname:         homer
    person_lname:         himpson
    person_age:           33
    prize_caption:        free beer for life
    prize_email:          prizes@abcbooze.com
    prize_category:       alchohol
'''))
aadocuments.append(yaml.safe_load('''
    person_fname:         helen
    person_lname:         himpson
    person_age:           16
    prize_caption:        free ammo for life
    prize_email:          prizes@zzzguns.com
    prize_category:       firearms
  '''))
```

Sample validation rule

```
- rule_caption:     check-underage-minor
  rule_vpath:       '[@]|[? @.person_age < `18`]'
  validation_schema:
    prize_category:
      type: string
      allowed: ['pets','toys','candy']
    prize_email:
      type:     string
      regex:    '[\w]+@.*'
```

- The code above is a YAML formatted representation of a single validation rule taken from a list of rules.
- In plain english, this rule specifies:

  - If we come across a record in the dataset, where `person_age` is less than 18 then:

    - assert the `prize_category` field exists
    - assert the `prize_category` field is of type string
    - assert the value of `prize_category` is either `pets` or `toys` or `candy`
    - assert the `prize_email` field exists, of type string
    - assert the `prize_email` field matches a specific regular expression

#### Example outcome

- The outcome for `helen himpson` in the above example would be `validation-fail`.

  - the `check-underage-minor` validation rule triggers, because `person_age == 16`
  - `prize_cateogry` has the value `firearms`, which is not permitted, so validation fails

#### Rationale

- This approach can be extended to any arbitrary level of complexity.
- This approach is easily comprehensible by humans (although the jmespath syntax can be a challenge)
- Any arbitrarily complex set of conditions and constraints can be established using this approach.

#### Pitfalls

- The above example uses jmespath syntax to specify `rule_vpath`, which tells the system to trigger this specific rule if and only if `person_age` exists and is less than 18. This adds a dependency on jmespath.

#### See also

- [complete code example on github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dreftymac/trypublic/master/lab2019/composite-validation/demo_composite_validation_001a.py)